# Powershell - how to replace OS Version number with String

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am querying remote servers for their operating system. I know that I can return the Version, but I want to replace these values with the friendly name. The code I have so far is:

```
$Computer = (gc c:\servers.txt)
$BuildVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Property Version, CSName -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Build=$BuildVersion.version
   If ({$BuildVersion.Version -match "5.2.3790"}) 
          {$Build="2003"}
   Elseif ({$BuildVersion.Version -match "6.1.7601"}) 
           {$Build="2008"}
   Elseif ({$BuildVersion.Version -like "6.3.9600"}) 
          {$Build="2012"}
```

But this doesn't seem to work and only returns "2003" regardless. Please help, I'm fairly new to PS and coding.

thanks

Comment: {No need {to} wrap {everything} {in {braces}}} inside the `if ()` bits.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Unbalanced braces :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption
```

Additionally you can see everything this WMI object holds like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | fl *
```

Edit: if you want to remove some text from the string, you can use `-replace`:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption) -replace "Microsoft Windows Server ",""
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks this works!! Just one thing, I need to remove the word "Microsoft Windows Server " (and the space after it) so it will just say something like: "2012 R2 Datacenter" etc. Thanks

Comment: You should read all the other answers. They explain why you were wrong, whereas my answer only allows you to circumvent the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your `if` statements.  Putting the Boolean expression inside squiggly brackets makes it a script block, and that's going to get cast as a string before being cast as a Boolean.  Strings cast to Booleans always evaluate to true unless they're empty.

```
PS C:\> {$BuildVersion.Version -match "5.2.3790"}
$BuildVersion.Version -match "5.2.3790"
PS C:\> ({$BuildVersion.Version -match "5.2.3790"}) -as [bool]
True
PS C:\> $BuildVersion.Version -match "5.2.3790"
False
PS C:\> ($BuildVersion.Version -match "5.2.3790") -as [bool]
False
```

So what you're running is essentially:

```
if ([bool]'$BuildVersion.Version -match "5.2.3790"') [...]
```

And that's always going to be true.

Try:

```
$Computer = (gc c:\servers.txt)
$BuildVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Property Version, CSName -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$Build=$BuildVersion.version
If ($BuildVersion.Version -match "5.2.3790") 
{
    $Build = "2003"
}
Elseif ($BuildVersion.Version -match "6.1.7601") 
{
    $Build = "2008"
}
Elseif ($BuildVersion.Version -like "6.3.9600") 
{
    $Build = "2012"
}
```

Bottom line is that **squiggly brackets are not parentheses** and you can't use them like they are.

However, there's also a major logic error here.  You're potentially fetching an array for `$BuildVersion` because you're reading from a file, but then you treat it like a single value.  You never loop through `$BuildVersion`.  However, I do not have enough information about what you're actually trying to do with your script (like what you do with `$Build`) to be able to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

I originally said this, but I've since changed my mind

*The reason this is only returning `2003` is that you're only running your If code on a single entry in the list.*

**Wrong**

As TessellatingHeckler says, the reason your if wasn't working is that you had too many curly braces, so PowerShell wasn't actually evaluating your logic.

However, you still need to step through each of the computers to do what you're trying to do.  We'll do that by adding in a ForEach loop. I also went ahead and replaced your `If {}` logic with a `Switch` statement, which I think is easier to understand for a scenario like this with multiple clauses.  If's just get way too verbose.

Finally, I'm assuming you want to output the results too, so I added a custom object here, which is just a way of choosing which properties we want to display.

```
$Computer = (gc c:\servers.txt)
ForEach ($system in $computer){
    $BuildVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Property Version, CSName -ComputerName $system -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    $Build=$BuildVersion.version

    switch ($build){
        "5.2.3790" {$Build="2003"}
        "6.1.7601" {$Build="2008"}
        "6.3.9600" {$Build="2012"}

    }

    #output results
    [pscustomobject]@{Server=$system;OSVersion=$build;CSName=$buildVersion.CSname}        
}#EndOfForEach
```

### Output

```
>Server   OSVersion CSName  
------   --------- ------  
dc2012   2012      DC2012  
sccm1511 2012      SCCM1511
```

Comment: "*The reason this is only returning 2003 is that you're only running your If code on a single entry in the list*" - really? I'm convinced that it's because `if ({scriptblock}) {}` returns true because scriptblocks are truthy, regardless of the code inside them. e.g. `if ({$true -eq $false}) { "hi" }` outputs `"hi"`, so the first one always triggers...? But nobody else is saying that, so I feel I'm missing something.

Comment: I think  you're right!  I ended up removing his whole if structure because it was too curly for my tastes.

Comment: `{ $false }` evaluates to `$false` alone. But `if({ $false }) ...` is just behaving crazy to me !